# write two outputs to columns in csv file python

Tags: python, file, csv

I am trying to create a csv file using my two output values, the first output will be the column name and the second will be the data. How will i go about this with the code i currently have?

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
import sys

for _, element in etree.iterparse("F:\Datasets\learning_dataset\PKDD2007-Dataset.xml"):
if element.text and not element:
    print element.tag, element.text
```

The output i get from this is:

```
os UNKNOWN
webserver APACHE
runningLdap UNKNOWN
runningSqlDb UNKNOWN
runningXpath FALSE
Connection: close
Accept: */*
Accept-Charset: *;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: compress;q=0.1
Accept-Language: apnalTo-mD;q=0.6, asdn-Ee, eai-5ns;q=0.0
```

Comment: Use JSON or INI instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want a 2-colum CSV from that, you can use something like

```
print '"%(tag)s","%(text)s"' % element
```

to get proper formatting (assuming `python2.x` from the `print` statement in your snipplet). To send the output to a file, you can simply use shell (or `cmd`) output redirection or write the file directly from the script via `open()` and `write()`.